# non-numeric argument from user input

Tags: perl

In this code the user is asked to input a number from the keyboard. The variable is then used again at a later point in division.

When the code is run it receives a

> 360/(whatever number was typed) isn't numeric in addition.

Is Perl interpreting the user input as a string instead of a numeric value?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Language::Logo;

print "Enter a number: ";
chomp(my $number = <STDIN>);

my $lo = new Logo(title => "Logo Demonstration");
$lo->command("update 2; color random; pendown; hideturtle");

for ( my $i = 1; $i < 999; $i++ ) {
    my $distance = $i / 4;
    $lo->command("forward $distance; right 360/$number");
}

$lo->disconnect("Press ctrl+c to exit");
```

Comment: Every user input read from STDIN or a file is a string, just like every commandline argument. Strings looking like a number in perl can be used as numbers without type casting, though. It seems the `command` method expects `right <some number>` and not `right <number>/<number>`. You have to do the division yourself first. The module does not do that for you.

Comment: I didn't even think about doing the division outside. The answer is always staring me right in the face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try:

```
$lo->command("forward $distance; right " . (360/$number));
```

If that doesn't work, try to force Perl to "see" $number as a number by adding 0 to it:

```
$rotation = 360 / ($number+0); 
$command = "forward $distance; right " . $rotation;
$lo->command($command);
```

And if that doesn't work either, try to manually set $command to something that DOES work, and report back.

Comment: gets rid of the error, but does not execute correctly because the right command is no longer executed.

Comment: Updated my answer